# /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory

Tags: make

I encountered some problems when compiling `gutenprint-5.2.9.tar.bz2`:

```
./extract-strings `cat xml-stamp | sed -e 's;^;./;'` > xmli18n-tmp.h.tmp
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
Makefile:827: recipe for target 'xmli18n-tmp.h' failed
make[4]: *** [xmli18n-tmp.h] Error 255
```

I’m building on Ubuntu 16.04, using the `cc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2012.12-20121214_linux` cross-compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Gutenprint doesn’t support cross-compiling: its build process compiles tools which it later needs to run, without distinguishing between the host compiler and the target compiler. In fact, even its `configure` script isn’t cross-compiler-friendly since it relies on host-specific configuration tools.

The specific error you’re seeing means that `extract-strings` was cross-compiled for `armhf`, so it needs the `ld-linux-armhf.so.3` ELF interpreter; but that’s not available on your system.

Comment: I unpacked the x86 and arm versions, then compiled x86, and ported the x86 tools to the arm.